# Jenkins - Cancel Uninstall Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I clicked uninstall for a plugin and now the Plugin Manager is showing me "Uninstallation pending" for that plugin, however, I have decided to keep the plugin. Since I cannot restart Jenkins and reinstall it at the moment, is there a way that I can cancel the request to uninstall this plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage it somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution other than waiting for a window to restart Jenkins.

Answer (score 5):

Jenkins plugin's are under $JENKINS-HOME/plugins, [plugin].jpi files (similar content to war files, WEB-INF, META-INF) are located under this folder.

Jenkins extract these files into folder with the same name

```
$ ls $JENKINS-HOME/plugins/gradle*
gradle.jpi //installation file 
gradle.jpi.pinned // flag file for pinned plugin 
gradle.jpi.disabled // flag file for disabled plugin 
gradle.bak // previous version jpi file
gradle: // extracted folder
help-GradleInstallation-home.html  help-GradleInstallation-name.html  help.html  META-INF  WEB-INF
```

- if [plugin].jpi.pinned exists the plugin is pinned

[image]

- if [plugin].jpi.disabled exists the plugin is disabled

[image]

- when you upgrade plugin the old [plugin].jpi is renamed to [plugin].bak
  the new one is [plugin].jpi this allows the rollback (downgrade) option
  [image]

  - if  [plugin].jpi is missing the plugin is pending uninstallion, on next restart Jenkins will delete all the files relevant to the plugin

  [image]

So,
all you need to do is copy the [pluging].jpi* and [plugin] folder into $JENKINS-HOME/plugins/ folder and refresh the page, you will see it is not pending uninstall anymore.

*always recomanded to keep backup of $JENKINS-HOME dir